# Hide my IP address from gmail headers when sending mails via python SMTP library?

Tags: python, gmail

I am currently using python SMTP library to send e-mails to certain clients.
I am using the smtp.gmail.com:587 server.
I noticed that in the original headers of any received e-mails sent by this code, the IP address of my own server which sent the e-mail appears.
How can I hide this information ?

Thanks in advance.

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    #server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login("my gmail account", "gmail account passwd")
    server.sendmail(source, [destination], message)
    server.quit()
```

Headers received by such an email.

```
    Delivered-To: XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX.com
    Received: by 10.52.117.49 with SMTP id kb17csp32285vdb;
    Thu, 5 Dec 2013 09:23:19 -0800 (PST)
    X-Received: by 10.66.235.106 with SMTP id ul10mr89187198pac.19.1386264198756;
    Thu, 05 Dec 2013 09:23:18 -0800 (PST)
    Return-Path: <noreply@XXXXXXX.com>
    Received: from mail-pd0-f172.google.com (mail-pd0-f172.google.com [209.85.192.172])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v7si58653928pbi.128.2013.12.05.09.23.18
    for <XXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.com>
    (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
    Thu, 05 Dec 2013 09:23:18 -0800 (PST)
    Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 209.85.192.172 is 
    neither permitted nor denied by
    best guess record for domain of   
    noreply@XXXXXXXXX.com) client-ip=209.85.192.172;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
    spf=neutral (google.com: 209.85.192.172 is neither 
    permitted nor denied by best guess 
    record for domain of noreply@XXXXXXX.com) 
    smtp.mail=noreply@XXXXXXXXXXXX.com
    Received: by mail-pd0-f172.google.com with SMTP id g10so25045148pdj.31
    for <XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX.com>; Thu, 05 Dec 2013 09:23:18 -0800 (PST)
    X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
    h=x-gm-message-state:message-id:date:from:to:cc:subject;
    bh=q/9aftTaFh6ryLKbZzIDy6Hfz1R4BSYhG2tvHwxCBLU=;
     b=C7Ke+Q6gVau5OxK9BZTuFx2ny0lO35WRjgsWoGyjlbQ0hlTRyQbD18ALNnlbdowUzR
     JHO8Smvr2EpgTFQ6h9gsLx6V8fmrfpFNWyQWOFgs6h46d9b1TTW7LWQZfVOIfWD6CfgG
     7hUTl7/YFcLbuUQpcOMUDJ/LK7AN4Yp6J6n2nzA6m46QOKKSP7t62OCUTlCd9JoLg4D3
     zPkF7oFptlyHWwpZCN5FozbqjuLx6rQfaZpKKMd2q4OXsPd0/CwtOOpBaf1BNVF7HOnD
     VJR8YrpFI/gpUOfJJz9R5l8DXE8KAkMCW+10OAupdTzwP9gtSk2coHBA+N05Q2ezzDuK
     Np3w==
     X-Gm-Message-State:   ALoCoQn41Nai7QBm96wqd4aNJPrBfx2AlYr+PlZzQ
     wAxujazDPTnRQG80l4v/Oy35W/3ZIz6jCIa 
     X-Received: by 10.68.66.103 with SMTP id e7mr53292154pbt.120.1386264197850;
     Thu, 05 Dec 2013 09:23:17 -0800 (PST)
     Return-Path: <noreply@XXXXXXXXX.com>
     Received: from [127.0.0.1] ([xx.xxx.xxx.xx])
     by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id er3sm145968195pbb.40.2013.12.05.09.23.15
     for <XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXx.com>
     (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
     Thu, 05 Dec 2013 09:23:16 -0800 (PST)
     Message-ID: <52a0b684.a363440a.5bbc.ffff8e2e@mx.google.com>
     Date: Thu, 05 Dec 2013 09:23:16 -0800 (PST)
     From: noreply@XXXXXXXXXX.com
     To: XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX.com
     Cc: 
     Subject: FTP Credentials

     Your FTP account credentials are:
     User Name = xxxxxxxxxxx
     Password = xxxxxx
```

Comment: Please paste all of the headers of such an email, XXX-ing out any confidential details.

Comment: Google includes the IP if you use SMTP but not if you use the web interface. There's a python project which uses the webmail interface called libgmail - http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/ not sure how up to date it is and it will surely violate the Gmail TOS.

Comment: I attached the headers, the IP crossed out with 'x' characters is my own server's IP.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated and thank a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

Those headers are added by the gmail SMTP server. There is no way to hide them.

Comment: I understand that gmail hides the sender's IP address if the email is sent from a gmail web client for example and that this header is added by google SMTP servers but then how is it the case that a lot of emails sent from a wide variety of sources do not have the sender's IP displayed in the headers ? A lot of these emails are sent by clients very similar to the python SMTP client I am using. Is there something I am missing ??

Thanks for your quick reply :)

Comment: `a lot of emails sent from a wide variety of sources do not have the sender's IP displayed in the headers` What's your source for that? In the headers, a receiving mailserver will indicate from what source they received the message; the first hop (in this case, Gmail) will show the sender source, unless that mailserver is mis/mal-configured.

Comment: I do not have a specific source for that however I did check a wide variety of e-mails in my mailbox from different sources and the only header I noticed was the one where I received the email from a google mailserver (IP indicated in the header) however the originating IP address from which the email was sent and received by the mailserver was not there :)

Comment: For example, I will paste the headers of an email I received. It only shows the IP address of the mail server I got the email from however no IP related to the source from which the message was received.

Comment: Delivered-To: mostafa.ali11791@gmail.com
Received: by 10.140.49.130 with SMTP id q2csp225192qga;
        Thu, 28 Nov 2013 03:30:47 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.224.29.66 with SMTP id p2mr57652323qac.82.1385638246878;
        Thu, 28 Nov 2013 03:30:46 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <000001429e79b6fe-7478ce1a-36d5-4d5b-99d9-ac223f8c8bf5-000000@amazonses.com>
Received: from b232-85.smtp-out.amazonses.com (b232-85.smtp-out.amazonses.com. [199.127.232.85])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id i9si18529724qce.46.2013.11.28.03.30.46
        for <mostafa.ali11791@gmail.com>;

Comment: "IP addresses can be considered sensitive information. As such, Gmail may hide sender IP address information from outgoing mail headers in some circumstances." https://support.google.com/mail/answer/26903?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using VPN service like HIDE-MY-IP. They allow you to use different IP from proxies, and not use your own. This way you mask your IP with another one...

Answer (score 0):

I  could swear I just checked and gmail was still forwarding x-originating-ip - if not that's great.  In the name pf privacy yeah right its in the name of that's our marketing information but anyways - If they do not forward your IP then you are still at risk of having your IP located with many other simple techniques.

Don't kid yourself - Google does track IP addresses there is simply a reason its not in certain cases based on sender and receiver control/ownership.

From here if you decide its not safe enough to simply trust the next email will not contain x originating or that its not tracked in a easy to retrieve way then you can move up the scale:

Public Proxy Configuration and Testing/Validation  Cheap, fast, pretty easy but so many way for this to be useless its barely better than going to the library except that  a free proxy outta russia may make your email look suspicious or end up in junkmail and many proxy's proxy your IP as well lol

Paid Premium Proxy Services or "Endpoint Protection" such as Anonymizer, Hushmail (server enforced encryption signing and anonymity) ,  Symantec, or DELL...  From a few dollars a month to buckets of cash as joe trucker and the president are both clients to somebody that offers this service at different scales.

Enter open source peer to peer encrypted onion like puzzles over the Tor protocol.  Tor is what makes wikileaks work. It's also the entire darknet and is useful in a context of freedom and privacy.  The Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) is ok for short term usage

The only serious solution is Tor on a custom live OS that has all the caveats taken care of.

US DoD Anonymous Live Distribution:

http://spi.dod.mil/lipose.htm

And Whonix is a good implementation of Tor that appears to solve a lot of accidental leakages of IP address since it forces all internet through Tor no matter what.  Compare this one to others however its probably sufficient:

https://www.whonix.org/